# Angular: Proper way to use ng-change on this special case?

Tags: angularjs

I have a little issue with a filter, actually I have around 3 issues that I am here to see if you could help. My guess was: I can fix it with an `ng-change` but I just realized that doesn't work that way or I am using it incorrectly.

Lets start.

I have search input:

```
<input ng-model="query">
```

and then I have to things to work along with that input:

```
<div ng-repeat="sport in sports | filter:query">
  <div ng-show="sport.leagues.length">
    <strong>{{sport.name}}</strong>
  </div>

  <div ng-repeat="league in sport.leagues | filter:query">
     {{league.name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

as you can see above, that was my guess at first, and also I tough that removing `|filter:query` from the second `ng-repeat` should work BUT NOT.

Then I did 2 different inputs with 2 `ng-model` and works properly, I was reading the Angular Docs and I decided to use an `ng-change` so I did it this way:

```
<input ng-model="query" ng-change="query=queries">

<div ng-repeat="sport in sports | filter:query">
  <div ng-show="sport.leagues.length">
    <strong>{{sport.name}}</strong>
  </div>

  <div ng-repeat="league in sport.leagues | filter:queries">
     {{league.name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

but that way the search input just don't work, you can not type anything there.

I though it was easy stuff, `sport.name` and `league.name` are arrays both so there is no issue with that due to angular filters works only with arrays. I do not know what is going.

Any suggestions ?

**UPDATE**

my code works properly on the first `ng-repeat`, the issue I have is on the second `ng-repeat` which is `league in sport.leagues`

Comment: Can you create  plunker?

Comment: actually here I have a [Plunkr of this](http://plnkr.co/edit/FJ45nV6gdwp3SkRglPeW?p=preview), is working properly, I guess my problem is due to single page app, and the time that the data loads, there is something missing, or something loading after the filters get called.

Comment: You cant type anything there means what????

Comment: I mean 'nothing' the input just becomes like disabled or something similar. You can not type anything. @micronyks

Comment: it should be <input type="text" ng-model="query"/>... have you tried this. you snippet has wrong input ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="text" ng-model="query" placeholder="search your text">


<div ng-repeat="sport in sports | filter:query"> //filtering is done based on model that  your are binding to filter pipe. Hope json is in format as required.
  <div ng-show="sport.leagues.length">
    <strong>{{sport.name}}</strong>
  </div>

  <div ng-repeat="league in sport.leagues | filter:query">
     {{league.name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it is not working by changing the type of the input to ```type="text"``` any other suggestion ?

Comment: still you are not able to type? or filtering is not happening?

Comment: I wonder with whats wrong. you plunker is working completely... so wrong with it?

Comment: when I am unable to type is when I put the ```ng-change```

Comment: check your json. or provide your code which is not working with plunker.

Comment: ng-change is not required here. (if you have any scenario then its fine, else not needed)...

Comment: this is the json http://storage4.static.itmages.com/i/15/0123/h_1422027246_4274058_6edf7b8379.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69456/discussion-between-micronyks-and-theunnamed).